# Paginating long article

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to paginate a long article for viewing on mobile for a site built on the codeigniter framework.
I've been able to determine the number of pages for the article, but am lost on how create the links and being able to pass arguments to the uri for the pagination.
This is my code from my controller

```
function view_post($alias)
      {
           $post = $this->post_model->load_post($alias);
           $data['title'] = $post->post_title;
           $data['logged'] = $this->ion_auth->logged;
           $data['user_id'] = $this->ion_auth->user;
           $data['username'] = $this->ion_auth->username;  
           $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->count_post_comments($post->ID);
           $link = strtolower($post->name)."/".$post->alias;
           $data['post_link'] = "www.giggsmagazine.com/".$link;
           $data['post'] = $post;

           // Article Pagination for long articles
           $posts = explode("&lt;!-- pagebreak --&gt;",$post->post_content);
           $page_count = count($posts) - 1;
           $data['pages'] = $page_count;
           $data['posts'] = $posts;
           if($this->isMobile())
          {
              $device = $this->agent->mobile;
              switch($device)
              {
                  case "BlackBerry":
                  $this->load->view('mobile/bb/inc/bb_header',$data);
                  $this->load->view('mobile/bb/posts/view_post');
                  $this->load->view('mobile/bb/inc/bb_footer');
                  break;
                  case "Apple Iphone" || "Apple Ipod Touch":
                  $this->load->view('mobile/iphone/inc/iphone_header',$data);
                  $this->load->view('mobile/iphone/posts/view_post');
                  $this->load->view('mobile/iphone/inc/iphone_footer');
                  break;
                  default:
                  $this->load->view('mobile/generic/inc/generic_header',$data);
                  $this->load->view('mobile/generic/view_post');
                  $this->load->view('mobile/generic/inc/generic_footer');
                  break;
              }
           }else {
           $this->load->view('templates/site_header',$data);
           $this->load->view('posts/view_post');
           $this->load->view('templates/site_footer');
           }
      }
```

Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far? You'd probably be better off paginating it client side with javascript/jQuery (just a simple 'read more' link would do, capping the data to a certain character limit), but if you want to do it server side using the code you've already written, you'd probably do something like this:

Add a new 'page' parameter to view_post:

```
function view_post($alias, $page = 0)
```

Create a new variable for your post content

```
$data['post_content'] = $posts[$page];
```

And to display pagination, put something like this in your view:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $page_count; $i++) {
  echo "<a href='/path/to/view_post/{$alias}/{$i}'>{$i}</a>";
}
```

This should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has [its own Pagination library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) - why not use that?

Comment: am paginating a long article not database records

Comment: CI's pagination library does not require a set of database records to work off - but hey, whatever floats your boat :)